# Viewing Chinese/Korean/Lunar birthday on org-agenda?

Tags: emacs, calendar, org-mode, chinese-locale

I have a few people around me who use Lunar Calendar instead of Gregorian one, so my current set up:

```
*** Birthdays
:PROPERTIES:
:CATEGORY: Birthday
:END:
**** NAME <1980-09-09 Thu +1y>
```

fails to show up at the right time on `org-agenda`.

I know that there is `calendar-chinese-date-string` function that changes the Gregorian date to a Chinese one, but I don't know how that would work within `.org` file.

Any help?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to convert the date into Gregorian? Or do you want to keep the date in Lunar but have it show up up in `org-agenda` as Gregorian?

Comment: @Brian Malehorn To be honest, the only way I would ever encounter the birthday would be through org-agenda, so as long as the birthday gets displayed on the agenda at the right time, then I don't really care how the original is kept.

Comment: @BrianMalehorn Sorry, just realized that I tagged you incorrectly and couldn't find the edit button on the comment above

Comment: I have [the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085749/how-to-define-hebrew-anniversaries-to-show-up-in-org-agenda). Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @user1876484 No not yet.

Answer (score 0):

If You just want to display important dates on lunar calendar, you can try following:

```
**** TODO Mother's birthday  
   <%%(diary-chinese-anniversary 1 1)>
```

This will show up on lunar calendar's 1st day of 1st month every year.